# Target/output mismatch using SentencePieceTokenizer layer with HuggingFace dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers, sentencepiece, keras-nlp

I am trying to test a simple model using a SentencePieceTokenizer layer
over a (HuggingFace) dataset. But I seem unable to get the shape of
the dataset's target to agree with the model's output. All code
available here](https://github.com/rbelew/rikHak/blob/master/tst_240311.py)

First, I get the dataset from HF and convert it to the tensorflow
version that `keras.Model.fit()` expects using

```
trainDS = LH_dataset_HF['train'].to_tf_dataset(
        columns=["text"],
        label_cols=["answer"],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        )
```

I can demonstrate the data is loaded and the SPTokenizer is working as
expected:

```
trainTF shape=(6, 3) answer shape=(6,)
all answers=[b'Yes' b'Yes' b'Yes' b'No' b'No' b'No']
echo1:  b'My roommate and I were feeling unwell in our basement apartment for a long ...
```

My model begins with a `keras_nlp.tokenizers.SentencePieceTokenizer`
layer, has one embedding layer, and then makes a prediction:

```
Model: "functional_1"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape           ┃       Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ input_layer (InputLayer)        │ (None)                 │             0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ sentence_piece_tokenizer        │ (None, 32)             │             0 │
│ (SentencePieceTokenizer)        │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ embed (Embedding)               │ (None, 32, 100)        │     1,000,000 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ predictions (Dense)             │ (None, 32, 1)          │           101 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
Total params: 1,000,101 (3.82 MB)
Trainable params: 1,000,101 (3.82 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
```

But when I try to `model.fit(trainDS)`  I get

> ValueError: Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same rank
> (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None,), output.shape=(None, 32, 1)

I also did an experiment using `map` to transform the string labels to integers:

```
def binaryLbl(txt,tlbl):
    return(txt,1 if tlbl=='Yes' else 0)

trainDS2 = trainDS.map(binaryLbl)
```

but `trainDS2.element_spec()` now says the label has NO shape?!

> (TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))

Why is does `target.shape=(None,)` How should I make it match the single `prediction` output node of the model?

### Package versions

```
torch=2.1.0.post100
torchtext=0.16.1
tensorflow=2.15.0
tensorflow_text=2.15.0
keras=3.0.5
keras_nlp=0.7.0
```

Comment: keras-nlp is its early stage, so for the time being, it is better to reach them via github ticket.

Comment: hi @Innat, but this issue doesn't depend on keras_nlp?  The SentencePiece tokenizing is working fine, it's just matching the dataset's labels with the model's predictions that isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked. I tried to run your code but it seems `collate_fn` is missing. Could u please share [full code](https://github.com/rbelew/rikHak/blob/master/tst_240311.py) that reproduce the error. Also please remove the torch related import if backend is set to tensorflow.

Comment: the full code runs to the end error message "ValueError: Arguments target and output must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None,), output.shape=(None, 32, 1)" for me?  thanks for looking at it

Comment: (and i removed the references to torch as you requested; no impact on results)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still, the given code is not reproducible the error. Could you please run your code on colab or kaggle env and share the link (instead of github link)? Genrally, the error you mentioned states the exact issue, the target shape and model's ouput shape must be shape to compute loss/metrics etc.

Comment: ok, with some effort (moving data, conforming to colab environment, ...) i think i've done it:  i'm not sure sharing a link to this colab notebook is appropriate tho?  can we take that bit offline, or...?